# CSS Table responsiveness format

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-table

I have not found the exact example for this so please point me to a link if you have.

I want to make a table in HTML be responsive as follows - is it possible with CSS?

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <td>HEADER Data 1</td>
         <td>HEADER Data 2</td>
         <td>HEADER Data 3</td>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
         <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
         <td>Row 1 Data 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
         <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
         <td>Row 2 Data 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Row 3 Data 1</td>
         <td>Row 3 Data 2</td>
         <td>Row 3 Data 3</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

On small screens I want the table responsive so that is places the data as follows:

```
HEADER Data 1
Row 1 Data 1
Row 1 Data 2
Row 1 Data 3

HEADER Data 2
Row 2 Data 1
Row 2 Data 2
Row 2 Data 3

HEADER Data 3
Row 3 Data 1
Row 3 Data 2
Row 3 Data 3
```

Comment: not tables but definitely with divs, lookup `table-cell`

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-table-roundup/

Comment: Are you sure for small screens you want to group by row, or do you want to group by column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this will help in making a table responsive.

> Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4m4ex229/)

**HTML :**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Age</td>
            <td>Gender</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Qasim</td>
            <td>23yrs</td>
            <td>Male</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ali</td>
            <td>19yrs</td>
            <td>Male</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>William</td>
            <td>34yrs</td>
            <td>Male</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS :**

```
td{
  width:100px;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    thead {
        display: none;
    }
    tr{
      display:grid;
      border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
    }
    td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Name"; }
    td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Age"; }
    td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Gender"; }

    td:before{
      width:150px;
      float:left;
    }
    td{
      width:300px;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put a copy of each header inside the corresponding row, and hide it with the CSS pseudo-selector `:first-child`. Then use media query to change the layout, hide the normal headers, and display the hidden headers.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>HEADER Data 1</td>
            <td>HEADER Data 2</td>
            <td>HEADER Data 3</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>HEADER Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HEADER Data 2</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HEADER Data 3</td>
            <td>Row 3 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 3 Data 2</td>
            <td>Row 3 Data 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
tbody tr td:first-child {
    display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    thead {
        display: none;
    }
    td {
        display: block;
        clear: left;
    }
    tbody tr td:first-child {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flowstoneknight/37r7pv6j/).